# When determining the type of critical point of an almost linear system, what does it mean when one of the eigenvalues is 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One of my eigenvalues is 0, and my textbook says nothing of this situation.
For example, is the critical point a node, saddle, etc. is it unstable/stable...

Comment: That means it is "flat" and you need to do more than just a linear approximation (which is what "eigenvalues" and "eigenvectors" give you).

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook is silent on this matter because there is not much to say. The node could be stable, unstable, asymptotically stable, or none of these. These systems can be frustrating to work with because you have to examine the nonlinear aspects of the differential equation. On the other hand, these systems can be more interesting once you have solved them.

Answer (score 1):

This case is often left out of treatments of almost linear systems.  Things are complicated: it could be either stable or unstable, it also might not be an isolated critical point.